# Unable to remove template from sitecore. Getting error "The template is used by at least one item"?

Tags: templates, sitecore

First, I made a backup for all items assigned old templates. Then, I created new templates and all items are assigned with the new templates.

After assigning new templates, there was something problem and I moved back to all items assigned old templates.

Then, I tried to remove the new templates, but Sitecore say that "The template is used by at least one item".

I can assume and check all moved back items and no items are using the new templates.

What is the issue??

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your Links database?

Comment: How do I rebuild the links database?

Comment: Log in to the desktop, go to Control Panel -> Rebuild Links database.
Also, the issue might appear because of the template having the __standard values. Might be worth removing that and giving it a try if that's also the case?

Comment: Press navigation tab, Links item,  to see the referrers

Answer (score 5):

Your template is being used by one or more content items. You can see which items it's using via the links menu:

[image]

You need to delete **all** of these content items **before** you can delete the template. I don't think there is a quick way of doing this unfortunately

Comment: The Links menu was the key to showing me what was refering to the item was attempting to remove.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but for others that have this issue, yes, the true fix is update the links database so that Sitecore knows the templates aren't actually referenced any longer.

If you actually just wanted to force delete the templates, you can use the SitecoreInstance.com/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx file to force delete which BYPASSES the built in check.
Note - if you use this to delete, you WILL NOT be able to click on any item (which you're saying there shouldn't be) that actually to refer to the template.  You'll have to use the DBBrowser to delete those items as well.  Be careful

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could use the [Template Usage Reporter](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Template_Usage_Reporter.aspx) sitecore module to determine which items sitecore thinks the current template is being used by.
Additionally - an alternative here is to use sitecore rocks to delete the template - it gives you additional user friendly options. I would run the Broken Links Report after this though - just to make sure things worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your standard value of the template :=)

Comment: Yes, I already deleted the standard values and could see there were no error. Thx for answering.